# How to modify object with the same shape using another object?

Tags: typescript

```js
type A = { a: number, b: string };

let obj1: A = { a: 1, b: "1" };
let obj2: A = { a: 2, b: "2" };

let propKey: keyof A;

for (propKey in obj1) {
  obj2[propKey] = obj1[propKey];
}

console.log(obj2);
```

How can I make the above code to compile?

Error:

```json
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Comment: Your type definition is wrong in the first place. You have to use a semicolon instead of a comma: `type A = { a: number; b: string };`

Comment: @ConradNeumann it has no difference

Comment: @ConradNeumann You don't technically *have* to, Typescript will compile the code just fine with commas. It's just better code style to use semicolons.

Comment: @ConradNeumann paste the above code to `https://www.typescriptlang.org/play` and change comma to semicolon, it is the same error.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAbigMwGdhiBLLAcygF9SAodgGwmCgHsCAKwCMmOIhQYoIgDQVMAchGLWHHn0FCATOITI0mbfMpRF21W04aoYYvzABpCCEwBrF-wBmsDuwDG-Fg0UF44WP76ADwAKvKOUBAAHsAQWAAmVFAeIN5QMQB8ABRaYvnyWrrl2S6YjgCUCAXI7FACwtoA2jkAuvql3S49HFbsXvzEUEV2Ds4gUAztoo1IraHh-iXCckvGtvZOLvUjQA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: If you want to copy property-by-property and have TypeScript be happy about it, you'll need to refactor to use *generics*.  Personally I'd just use `Object.assign()` given your exact example, but presumably you have some other use case.  Both types of approaches are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6GOvN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Jordan Wow, sorry for the confusion. I guess, I have become a bit blindfolded by my Linter settings.

Comment: @wonderflame better than ts-ignore thx ;) so works for me, but maybe there is more elegant method.

Comment: @drets as @jcalz mentioned without generics it would be just to use `Object.assign`, otherwise this is the easiest one without any assertions

Comment: @jcalz, wonderflame was first suggesting generics :D yeah, `Object.assign` doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: @wonderflame please post answer, I accept it then if nothing better exist.

Comment: @jcalz, do you have a brief explanation as to why the type of `obj2[propKey]` is `never`?

Comment: It's [ms/TS#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769); it prevents things like `obj2[Math.random()<0.5?"a":"b"] = 1`.  (`string & number` is `never`).  But it causes a lot of headache.  That's about as much as I want to go into on a comment section, especially since this comment probably will (should) be deleted as not directly on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jcalz mentioned in his comment the easiest way to copy property by property would be just using `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(obj2, obj1);
```

Alternatively, the shortest one would be having a generic function that would accept generic parameters for the type of objects and for the key:

```
const func = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj1: T, obj2: T, key: K) => {
  obj2[key] = obj1[key];
};
```

Usage:

```
let obj1: A = { a: 1, b: '1' };
let obj2: A = { a: 2, b: '2' };

let propKey: keyof A;

for (propKey in obj1) {
  func(obj1, obj2, propKey);
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAbigMwGdhiBLLAcygF9SAodgGwmCgHsCAKwCMmOIhQYoIgDQVMAchGLWHHn0FCATOITI0mbfMpRF21W04aoYYvzABpCCEwBrF-wBmsDuwDG-Fg0UF44WP76ADwAKvKOUBAAHsAQWAAmVFAeIN5QMQB8ABRaYvnyWrrl2S6YjgCUCAXI7FACwtoA2jkAuvql3S49HFbsXvzEUEV2Ds4gUAztoo1IraHh-iXCckvGtvZOLvUjQA)